# C++ SVG library to write path data

Tags: c++, image, svg

Does anyone know of a good C++ library which can generate SVG path data for me? The idea is that I should use simple MoveTo, LineTo, CurveTo commands etc and should get a final path string. Though its not that difficult and I can write my own, but in the interest of time, it would be better if something of this sort exists.

Comment: It's got to be c++ I suppose?

Answer (score 2):

Probably too late, but there's [Cairo](http://cairographics.org/) which is in C. And [libboard](http://libboard.sourceforge.net/) which is C++. And [simple svg](http://code.google.com/p/simple-svg/) in C++.

I have no affiliations with any of those.

Answer (score -1):

Qt provides a good SVG exporter and a good simple interface for drawing stuff:

```
QSvgGenerator generator;
generator.setFileName(path);
generator.setSize(QSize(200, 200));
generator.setViewBox(QRect(0, 0, 200, 200));
generator.setTitle(tr("SVG Generator Example Drawing"));
generator.setDescription(tr("An SVG drawing created by the SVG Generator "
                            "Example provided with Qt."));
QPainter painter;
painter.begin(&generator);


painter.fillRect(QRect(0, 0, 200, 200), Qt::darkGreen);
painter.setBrush(Qt::green);
painter.setPen(Qt::black);
    for (int y = -55, row = 0; y < 200; y += 50, ++row) {
        int xs;
        if (row == 2 || row == 3)
            xs = 150;
        else
            xs = 50;
        for (int x = 0; x < 200; x += xs) {
            painter.save();
            painter.translate(x, y);
            painter.drawPath(tree);
            painter.restore();
        }
    }


painter.fillRect(QRect(0, 0, 200, 200), Qt::gray);
painter.setPen(QPen(Qt::white, 4, Qt::DashLine));
painter.drawLine(QLine(0, 35, 200, 35));
painter.drawLine(QLine(0, 165, 200, 165));
painter.end();
```

See [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtsvg-svggenerator-example.html) for more details.